# how can I call a server side function in NanoHTTPD

Tags: java, android, nanohttpd, server-side-scripting

I'm running an Android things app to monitor devices and I'm using NanoHTTPD to allow the user to see whats happening on those devices. I would like to be able to provide a button on the webpage that can transition one of the gpIO pins. just a simple button but needs to pass an argument as to the pin to transition

example code (shrunk for simplicity)

```
public class Server extends NanoHTTPD {
    private final static int PORT = 8080;

    public Server() throws IOException {
        super(PORT);
        start();
        System.out.println("\nRunning! Point your browers to http://localhost:8080/ \n");
    }

@Override
    public Response serve(IHTTPSession session) {
        String msg = "<html><body><h1>IoT server </h1>\n";
        final Map<String, String> parms = session.getParms();
        msg += "<form action='?' method='SUBMIT'>\n";
        msg += "<input type='button' value='test' onclick=\"myFunction("+iLoop+")\">"; 
        msg += "<input name='Submit' type='submit' value='Submit' />";
        msg += "<script>";
        msg += "    function myFunction(f) {";
        msg += "        document.getElementById('Name1').value = 'Hi'+ eval(GetPin(f));";  // Something like this?
        msg += "    }";
        msg += "</script>";
        msg += "</form>\n";
        return new NanoHTTPD.Response(msg + "</body></html>\n");

    }


    String GetPin(String s) {

        // lots of code here but the net result is to return a value 

        return MyActivity.getIOPin(s)   
    }

}
```

Comment: And the question is? You can call anything you like in the serve() method...

Comment: I realize this, however I don't need to make this call when the page is initialized. I need to make it when a client presses a button on the page. As shown above after the page is first displayed to the user and the user presses the Test button whose on click event calls the function myFunction. At that point I want to call out to a function  I have created in my project called GetPin and have that value update a control